# Detecting if the user browser closes the browser

Tags: javascript

I have a website with master page. I want to catch a user trying to close the browser/tab. When I try using `onunload` in the body tag, it fires not only when I try closing the browser, but also when I navigate to another page.

Any idea how to only catch the event of closing the browser?

Comment: But if i want to code only for window close confirmation i.e. "yes or no" and it should not come while navigating from master page, clicking button ,refreshing page at that time what shoul i do ? can u write some sample code or logic

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. Javascript can only determine if the page you're on closes. If Javascript could determine whether other tabs and windows you're on closed, for example knowing if you closed down Facebook or Flyspray, that would be a major security risk. That's now how javascript works.

Comment: That's not actually what he's trying to do, but answers the question anyway :) Notice, he's not trying to detect other anything about other tabs. @santosh rahangdale, the onbeforeunload event doesn't make a difference between refresh, close tab/browser, going to another page, etc. they are all unload events.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with a secure wizzard online, that will save data through the process, and I needed to detect wether the client closed the tab and/or the browser, so far everything was going allright until I clicked the "continue" button to proceed to the next step, it threw me the same message, I've done quite some research on this and there is no way I'll be able to ignore the unload event that occurs when I navigate away from the pagethrough a link.

I tried to use the

```
if(window.event.clientY < 0 && window.event.clientX < 0){
    alert('holy damn! the window is closing!')
};
```

and some other methods that are around the web. none of them will be able to detect only the browser closing.  So as far as my research has advanced, there is no way to do this.